# How does the compiler guess the correct name when one mistypes it?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-construction

At times, `gcc` yields the following error message:

```
error: 'class X' has no member named 'Y'; did you mean 'Z'?
```

I have seen `gcc` correctly guess `Z` when `Y` contains some simple typo, *e.g. wrong lower/upper case*, but also when there are some missing/extra character(s) in the name.

I was curious to know

- how does `gcc` correctly guess `Z` starting from `Y`?
- if it applies a fixed set of rules, what kind of jamming is it able to handle and what falls beyond its grasp?

I would welcome answers relating other compilers too, if they perform something ostensibly different or interesting.

Comment: It probably uses something like Levenstein Distance.

Comment: this is a good question, however without knowing i would guess one of several options but i would guess a simple levenshtein distance or some other easy partial string matching algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after a quick search it seems that GCC has an internal code to handle spellcheck which includes an implementation of Levenstein distance.

see 
https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-09/msg01090.html
and 
https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-11/msg00046.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how GCC specifically does it, but there are algorithms that can calculate **how much** different are these two strings? Totally unrelated or a minor difference?

For example: Jaro-Winkler distance, Levenshtein distance, and maybe others.

So, when seeing an unresolved name, a compiler can scan through known/suitable names, pick one/few most similar and suggest that as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

GCC would likely already have a list of in-scope symbols at the ready, when it gets to a potentially incorrect symbol.  All it has to do then is run the incorrect symbol through a good old fashioned spellchecker algorithm, with the in-scope symbols as the dictionary.

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-09/msg01090.html